# Clover API not allowing connection using merchant api_token

Tags: clover-payment

I'm new to clover to if this seems elementary I apologize.

I logged into my merchant account and created an api_token. Got my mID from drop down menu on the top right. I try to do a simple request in postman like this

`https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/{mID}/items`

and the response I am getting back is this

`{ "message": "401 Unauthorized"}`

I made sure the user token I created has the correct priviledges already and it does.

I am NOT trying to create a public app for everyone to use. I am trying to create a private script that simply syncs MY clover inventory, back to my ecommerce site.

I don't understand the purpose of being able to generate an access token in your dashboard if they are going to make you create an app

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have had trouble with Clover too, when I was getting that 401 error it was because I was using the wrong merchant id.

In the image I have attached below initially I was using the mId that is shown under the blue box here. But, I found that the one I really needed to use for the mId is the text under the red box. It's a 13 character string, in my example abc123456789a.

In postman a get request to get merchant information for me worked correctly like this:

https://apisandbox.dev.clover.com/v3/merchants/{mId}

I provided headers: 
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Content-Type: application/json

I hope this can assist you in some way!

[image: merchant Id]

Comment: The Merchant Id that worked for me was a somewhat different one from the URL after logging into the dashboard.